# haml select tag not displaying a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to give an option of all shipment carriers available running a loop in haml.

```
%select.form-control{:name => 'shipment carrier'}
  - @result[:body].each do |carrier|
    %option{:value => carrier["carrier_id"]}
      = carrier["name"]
```

I've debugged in console by p'ing out `carrier["name"]` and each carrier name is being put out to the console. I'm new to haml so I believe it is the syntax

Comment: What HTML is being generated by this, and what are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `select_tag` helper to make your life easier.

> Expecting that @result[:body] = [{'carrier_id': '1', 'name': 'name'}, {'carrier_id': '2', 'name': 'name2'}]

```
- carrier_collection = @result[:body].collect{ |c| [c[:name], c[:carrier_id]] }
= select_tag :shipment_carrier, options_for_select(carrier_collection)
```

more about the `select_tag` http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag